# Forward traffic from public IP to namespace

Tags: linux, networking, routing, namespace, network-namespaces

I have two VMs VM-A & VM-B connected via IPIP Tunnel in a namespace. I want the application in VM-B which is under namespace to be accessed from the public IP of VM-C. Can someone help me how can this be done?
I am using the below commands for namespace in VM-B

```
ip tunnel add ipip0 mode ipip remote 129.56.12.78 local 172.31.47.255
ifconfig ipip0 mtu 1480 up
ip netns add proxy
ip link set ipip0 netns proxy
ip netns exec proxy ip link set dev ipip0 up
ip netns exec proxy ip link set dev ipip0 promisc on
ip netns exec proxy ip addr add 10.10.10.10/32 dev ipip0
ip netns exec proxy ip route add default dev ipip0

Public IP of VM-B = 13.126.56.89
Public IP of VM-C = 152.67.25.39
```

Comment: bump............

Comment: Bump............